# Would like to vectorize while loop for performance (updated)

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

1. Set values for a window of size n of an array based on the current value of another array
2. Ignore values that the window overrides
3. Need to be able to change the window size (n) for different runs

This code works but it is very slow.

```
    n = 3

    def signal(arr):
        signal = pd.Series(data=0, index=arr.index)
        i = 0
        while i < len(arr) - 1: 
            s = arr.iloc[i]
            if s in [-1, 1]:
                j = i + n
                signal.iloc[i: j] = s
                i = i + n
            else:
                i += 1
        return signal
```

```
arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

signal = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Can you make your question more clear that such as what is your input and what is your expect output? in code formation.

Comment: Updated:  arr is the input  - signal is the output

Comment: Please provide `arr` as machine readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make `arr` a pandas series object but just a `numpy` array.
Try this:

```
import numpy as np
def signal(arr, n):
    size = len(arr)
    signal = np.zeros(size)
    for i in range(size):
        s = arr[i]
        if s in [-1, 1]:
            j = i + n
            signal[i: j] = s
            i = i + n
        else:
            i += 1
    return signal
arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
n = 3

signal(arr, n)
```

I benchmarked the two different solutions and this is way faster:

- Original: 738 µs ± 21.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000
  loops each)
- New: 9.56 µs ± 778 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000
  loops each)

Comment: This needs the for loop replaced by `i = 0; while i < len(arr) :`. The `for i in range... ` resets i at each iteration and therefore removes the effect of `i=i+n`. It's significantly faster than anything else I tried.